# Domain name search (trying to find a site whose URL I forgot)

Tags: search, domain-name

The title pretty much says it all. What I have is a word, say 'frak', and a country code top-level domain and I'd like to search all the domains in that ccTLD in hopes of finding the site I'm looking for.

My Google search skills, which I am pretty proud of, haven't turned up anything useful.

Comment: This is not an answer to your query, but I recommend using Delicious.com for saving links that you may want to find again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allinurl: frak ccTLD
```

Googling that should narrow down the list.

Comment: I selected this answer even though the others are also great because it solves the problem with a single operator and is thus more elegant. That you all, tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can search in the url, so your best guess is to use

```
inurl:frak site:.com
```

as a lot of whois and DNS registrars don't allow to search through their domains.

You would have to find a site which explicitly stores domain names...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the search parameter "inurl" for a Google search, for example:

```
inurl:frak inurl:.<tld>
```

This looks in the whole URL, including folder and page names too, not just in the domain name, but could be a start